# Allow email from a particular sender through spam filter

Tags: exchange-2010, spam, spam-filter

We are running exchange 2010 and are using the built in anti-spam feature.

We have set up Content Filtering, IP Block List Providers, Sender ID, Sender Reputation and it filters out most of the junk but it also quarantines all emails from one of our customers.

It is being quarantined because of the Content Filter agent (Report Below). How can I add an exception for this email address to the Content Filter. I can see how to setup an exception for a delivery address ("Don't filter messages sent TO the following recipients") but I want to add customer@iinet.com.au to our safe list.

I don't want to add the whole domain as it is a very popular ISP in Australia and we often get junk from them.

Filter Report:

```
> Diagnostic information for administrators:
> 
> Generating server: something.com
> 
> person@something.com.au
> #550 5.2.1 Content Filter agent quarantined this message ##
> 
> Original message headers:
> 
> Received: from icp-osb-irony-out4.external.iinet.net.au (203.59.1.220)
> by  server.local.something.com.au (192.5.0.105) with Microsoft SMTP
> Server id
>  14.1.218.12; Mon, 5 Nov 2012 02:40:40 +1100 X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Filtered: true X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Result:
> AscOALeLllB8qwLw/2dsb2JhbABEKYUFhiigRQOWCwQEgQiBCIIZFAEBTiwCCAIBBwEIFDkBBBoqARoCAQIDAYd4uEuRXGEDiCWFT44UijeDAw
> X-IronPort-AV: E=Sophos;i="4.80,710,1344182400";    
> d="scan'208,217";a="55137861" Received: from unknown (HELO
> asdf83c05c53a3) ([124.171.2.240])  by  icp-osb-irony-out4.iinet.net.au
> with ESMTP; 04 Nov 2012 23:40:26 +0800 Message-ID:
> <E8C866D0299E4BCB8B156723893EB735@asdf83c05c53a3> From: Customer
> <customer@iinet.net.au> To: 'Person' <person@something.com.au>
> Subject: A long sentance Date: Mon, 5 Nov 2011 06:07:57 +1100
> MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0005_01C5F962.3CD09120" X-Priority: 3
> X-MSMail-Priority: Normal X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook Express
> 6.00.2900.5931 X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.2900.6157 Return-Path: customer@iinet.net.au Received-SPF: None
> (server.local.something.com.au: customer@iinet.net.au  does not
> designate permitted sender hosts)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open powershell via the exchange menu item and run those commands:

```
$list = (Get-ContentFilterConfig).BypassedSenders
$list.add("mail@domain.com")
Set-ContentFilterConfig -BypassedSenders $list
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : You should be using this one : [Microsoft Technet Configure Content Filtering Properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124490.aspx#ShellExceptions)

```
Set-ContentFilterConfig -BypassedSenders safesender@domain.com.au
```

The following is for Trusted Senders :

```
get-Mailbox | Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -TrustedSendersAndDomains @{Add='address@domain1.com','domain2.com'}
```

Above will set the trusted sender / domain for every user on your exchange. Have a read through at the following link for more information and examples.

http://beccabits.com/2011/10/07/how-to-bulk-modify-safe-senders-list-in-outlook-with-exchange-management-shell/

Hope this helps